# Eclipse Double Spaces code

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana, eclipse-3.6

Just opened the Eclipse Helios with Aptana to discover all of my code is now double spaced.  I assume this is a setting somewhere but can't figure out where.

How do I turn off double spacing in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You could try File > Convert Line Delimiters To > ... to convert line delimiters to different platform to see if it helps.